# Flutter Firebase delete a document of a subcollection using the document ID

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Apparently, I was able to retrieve a subcollection data from firebase by using the code below

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('announcementlist').where('id', isEqualTo: '${docID}');
```

However, I am now trying to delete a subcollection by using this collectionGroup method and it is not working. I want all admin user to be able to delete the subcollections.

So what I found online is something similar to this line of code.

```
// define document location (Collection Name > Document Name > Collection Name >)
var docRef = Firebase.firestore().collection("Rooms").doc("bsYNIwEkjP237Ela6fUp").collection("Messages");

// delete the document
docRef.doc("lKjNIwEkjP537Ela6fhJ").delete();
```

which I got from codegrepper but as far as I know, the *doc("bsYNIwEkjP237Ela6fUp")* part requires the id of the user which is not the method I want because all admin users should be able to delete the data and it uses collection instead of collectiongroup

Is there any solution for this ? Please help.

Comment: Can you share your firestore structure if possible? And did you create an index for the subcollection?

Answer (score -2):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Rooms").doc(snapshot.requireData.docs[i].id).collection("Messages").doc(snapshot.requireData.docs[i].id).delete();
```

Comment: Sorry but can u add more explanation?

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.